# AVAudioPlayer audio breaking and volume increases on its own

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I am calling this function `playSound()` in `viewWillAppear`, the audio starts playing and then suddenly volume increases with a minor break in playback.

here is my code

```
   func playSound() {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "music", withExtension: "mp3")!

    do {
        try self.player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        player?.prepareToPlay()
        player?.numberOfLoops = -1
        player?.play()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        KBLog.log(object: error.description)
    }}
```

**Edit 1 :**
I am using this code for an iPad app, so ipad only have speaker, no earpiece, if this has something to do with the issue.

Comment: Have you verified the source of this is not from the mp3 encoding? i.e. do you get the same effects playing the .mp3 in iTunes?

Comment: yes i have checked the audio source, it played normally in iTunes.

Comment: ok good, hope someone who knows more about AVAudioPlayer than me can help you out soon...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was i was playing this audio and at the same time i was initialising my publisher view for starting the video call, thus an instance of AVPlayer was initialised to take audio input i.e. two instances of AVPlayer were getting initialised causing the break in playback.